# Whats wrong with my route, sending arbitrary parameters with rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, routes

I'm a bit rusty with Rails. I'm trying to create a route that should accept an arbitrary number of parameters from a link_to, but I keep getting routing errors.

My link currently looks like this:

```
<%= link_to "Send Params", :action => "recieve", :controller => "pages", :name => "Test", :email => "test2" %>
```

And my route looks like this:

```
match 'pages/receive/*params' => 'pages#receive'
```

And I get:

```
No route matches {:action=>"recieve", :controller=>"pages", :name=>"Test", :email=>"test2"}
```

If I do:

```
<%= link_to "Send Params", :name => "Test", :email => "test2" %>
```

And:

```
match '/*params' => 'pages#receive'
```

It kinda works, but my method in the controller isn't getting called.

So, how should the route and link_to look?

Comment: Check the spelling of "receive"...

Comment: Globbing with `*params` is probably causing a conflict with the `params` helper method in your controllers and views.  Check out KL-7's answer below.

Comment: Also, the routing documentation is worth a read if you haven't done so already http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html

Comment: @MarkThomas Ah, saw the spelling error. Didn't help though. Wizard of Ogz: KL-7's answer probably works, but what I want to do is to be able to send/receive an arbitrary number of parameters, thought gobbling (*) could be used for that. My second example in my question kinda gives me the result I want, but I would prefer to have the receiving part in a separate action and page.

Comment: @Anders, why do you want gobbling? I believe that will prevent you from using convenient form of specifying arguments for `link_to` and other url helpers and you'll have to format your urls manually. And looks like gobbling packs everything into single parameter that means you'll have to parse it then to get your `name` and `email`.

Comment: @KL-7 It's for a school assignment. I have to be able send arbitrary parameters in the URL field with a link and receive them on another page, the user should also be able to add key/value pairs directly in the URL once the "receiving" page have loaded and display the new key/value pair on the page. Hope it make more sense now, so I can't use gobbling for that? :)

Comment: @Anders, I never used gobbling myself so I can't imagine a situation where it'd be more handy than regular get parameters. Though, I used smth like `:company/employee/1` and it was pretty handy as it accepts any company name in the first part and passes it as `params[:company]`. In your case I'm still not quite sure about requirements for the URL. But as you mentioned key/value pairs I can't help thinking about GET parameters. Theoretically, user can add any number of GET parameters on his own to the end of URL and the application will receive them all in `params` hash.

Comment: @Anders, maybe it'd be helpful if you describe what kind of URLs you want to process with your `PagesController#receive` action and add some examples of such URLs to your questions.

Comment: @KL-7 [Something like this](http://people.dsv.su.se/~pierre/courses/05_ass/ip2/2/2.1/perl/example.html). Try clicking the link on the page and then add some random key/value pair. It shouldn't be hard at all, but I kinda got stuck with link_to and my routes. Is it possible to use something like: `link_to "Test", :action => "receive", params[:params], :method => :get`? To active the same result? And how would the route look for that?

Comment: Ok, now it's clearer. And according to the URL from that example you're definitely supposed to use GET parameters and not some magic with stuffing parameters into URL with gobbling. Take a close look at the generated path I provided in the answer. And to show any number of GET parameters user passed to the server in your controller (or view) you can iterate over `params` hash and display all parameters you received.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Correct me if I'm wrong, but I think there is no need in this `*params` in you routes. You can do like that:

```
# routes.rb
get 'pages/receive', :to => 'pages#receive'

# in view
<%= link_to "Send Params", :action => "receive", :controller => "pages", 
                           :name => "Test", :email => "test2" %>

# it generates link with path like /pages/receive?name=Test&email=test2

# in PagesController#receive
name = params[:name]   # => "Test"
email = params[:email] # => "test2"
```

In Rails `params` is a helper method (that you can use in controllers and views) that returns a hash containing all GET and POST parameters.